# Interlocking circle div issue in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating this chart in Bootstrap using circular and rectangular divs - the only issue I have is that I need two of the circular divs on one line - interlocking in the middle like a ven diagram,

Should I use relative or absolute positioning maybe?

Can I use multiply blending too ?

This is the HTML markup

```
            <div class="white-grad" style="--b:12px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)">
            </div>
            <div class="white-grad" style="--b:12px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green); margin-bottom: 40px">
            </div>
```

This is the CSS I have so far:

```
.white-grad {
  --b:12px;  /* border width*/

  color: #313149;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.white-grad:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
.white-grad:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570));
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is give each of them a seperate ID and then you can shift one of them over the other.  Also make them both `display: inline-block;` instead of just block to get them side by side. Look what I did here:

```css
.white-grad {
  --b:12px;  /* border width*/
  color: #313149;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width:150px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.white-grad:after {
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
  padding-top:100%;
}
.white-grad:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570));
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),#fff calc(100% - var(--b)));
  border-radius:50%;
}


#grad2 {
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


            <div class="white-grad" id="grad1" style="--b:12px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)">
            </div>
            <div class="white-grad" id="grad2" style="--b:12px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green); margin-bottom: 40px">
            </div>
```

Comment: thank you John! This is awesome - I also tried flexbox - is this also a good idea?

Comment: @trailrunner89 for the display of `.white-grad`? you an use `display: inline-flex;` instead of `display: inline-block;` and it should still work.

Comment: Thanks John - I made a flex container around two of the  ```white-grad``` and then just used negative margins! The next challenge is to center text within them :(